# how to change silverlight hosting from "test page" to "web project"?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight

I have a project with two silverlight apps (foo1 and foo2) and an ASP.NET web service (foo.web).  When I created foo1, I configured it to be hosted in my web app by selecting "Link this Silverlight control into an existing web site" and then choosing foo.web as the site.  However when I created foo2, I chose "Automatically generate a test page to host Silverlight at build time instead".

I originally did this because I was not using the ASP.NET functionality for anything except hosting the page, and I thought I could save some mess.  However after doing a bit of development, I learn that I will get a security error if I try to use a WebClient when my application is hosted on a plain HTML page.  So it turns out I must host it through the ASP.NET application after all.

When I look at the projects' property pages, I don't see any difference that corresponds to my hosting choice.  I thought it would be under the "Silverlight" or "Debug" tabs, but those look the same in both projects.

What do need to change in project foo2 so that it will be hosted by an ASP.NET page in the web application (foo.web) instead of being hosted on a generated HTML page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The change is on the web project. Go to the Silverlight section and choose which Silverlight applications you'll be hosting in the web project. It will also generate test pages for you if you want.